# How to Start AWS instance if it has Tag exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to run AWS CLI command to start the instance if it has relevant Tags exist for Eg "MigratedBy". If Tag doesnt exists, it shouldnt start the instance at all

I tried running below command but it didnt work out

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:MigratedBy,Values=my-super-tag" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --outpu t text`
```

It seems this command would run all the instance with the tag "MigratedBy" but this is wrong in my case. I would like to just start the particular instance if tag exists otherwise not

Comment: That should have worked, the only issue I see is probably a typo: `--outpu t text` see the extra space there ... if you call the `describe-instances` does alone it return the instances expected?

Comment: You should always post the symptoms including any error messages rather than simply saying it doesn't work. Obviously this is a two-step process. If you run the describe-instances step alone, does it yield the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter based only on the existence of the tag you can include it in the query and then pipe to show only the InstanceId:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key=='MigratedBy'],InstanceId] | [*][1]' --output text
```

Finally, to start those instances the whole command will be:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key=='MigratedBy'],InstanceId] | [*][1]' --output text`
```

---

Reference:

[Filtering AWS CLI output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html)

Comment: the `--filters` work fine, are you saying they don't?

Comment: Using `--filters` you can filter based on a value. As I understand, you don't want to filter a specific value, only the existence of the tag key. Right?

Comment: Good point, I missed that in the question, maybe OP want to start those instance with tag `MigratedBy` and any value, but in that case why not use a wild card: `--filters "Name=tag:MigratedBy,Values=*"`

Comment: I think it should work too. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no error on my tests, only thing I could think of why the OP was having issues is the typo in the command, see at the end `--outpu t text`

Comment: This executes (start) all the instancesId if they dont have those tags (MigratedBy). I want to start only those instance which has Tag "MigratedBy" Otherwise it should skip the instance and remain as it is (on same state)

Comment: If you run `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:MigratedBy,Values=my-super-tag" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text` it returns instances without that Tag (MigratedBy)?